# How to count specific words in locked pdfs

Tags: pdf, word-count

How can I count specific words within a pdf file that is locked.

I am talking about annual reports here. You can search within, but you cant copy out of it (for whatever reason, doesnt make sense).

After googling forever, I still havent found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If your file contains text (and not just scanned images) and used fonts contains information about mapping from glyphs to characters then you should be able to extract text from the file using any PDF library that provides text extraction capabilities.

Copying of text is usually forbidden by setting usage rights. Many PDF libraries ignore these settings and allow text extraction from locked PDFs.

Depending on the library, you might try extracting whole text and splitting it into words yourselves or extracting text as collection of words (if library can split text into words for you).

Here is a sample code for [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) that shows how to build dictionary that contains information about words found in a PDF document and how many times they are used.

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> countWords(string file)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> wordCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(file))
    {
        foreach (PdfPage page in pdf.Pages)
        {
            PdfCollection<PdfTextData> words = page.GetWords();
            foreach (PdfTextData word in words)
            {
                int count = 0;
                wordCounts.TryGetValue(word.Text, out count);
                wordCounts[word.Text] = count++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return wordCounts;
}
```

Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of Docotic.Pdf.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to count the occurence of a two or more words string?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. `GetWords` retrieves ordered collection of words. I mean first element in retrieved collection is the leftmost and topmost word on a page. You might develop an algorithm that checks if a word is the first word of a multi-word string. If it is, then check for second one and so on.